# Shoot more than one bullet

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having problems with my character shooting. When **SPACE** button is pressed character shoot one bullet. But when I press **SPACE** for example twice I should got two bullets shoot from my character. Unfortunately I got only one bullet at the time and when my bullet collides with something (for example wall) only then other second bullet is shooted! I understand than ArrayList update only one bullet at the time and when that bullet is deleted then update another. How I need to get the double (or even more) Bullets effect?

Here is my Player class

```
public class CoolGuy extends GameObject{
      private ArrayList<PlayerBullet> bullets;
      /*Tones of code here */
    public void shoot(float delta){
        if(PlayerBullet.shoot){
            if(index != 0){
                index++;
            }
            bullets.add(new PlayerBullet(full.x, full.y + sprite.getHeight()/2 - 30));
        }
    }
    public void update(float delta) {
        if(bullets.size() > 0){
            if(bullets.get(index) != null){
                bullets.get(index).update(delta);
            }
            for(GameObject t : list){
                if(t instanceof Brick){
                    if(bullets.size() > 0 && bullets.get(index) != null && bullets.get(index).hits(t.getHitBox()) == 1){
                        bullets.remove(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Bullet class

```
public class PlayerBullet extends ItemObject{
    private Sprite sprite;
    private Rectangle full;
    public static boolean shoot;

    public PlayerBullet(int x, int y){
         ......
         ......
    }
    public int hits(Rectangle r) {
        if(full.overlaps(r)){
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void update(float delta) {
        full.x += (delta * 500);
        setPosition(full.x,full.y);
    }
}
```

And here in my main class

```
player1.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)){
        player1.shoot(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }
```

Comment: Your `update` method should probably start with something like `for (Bullet b : bullets) b.update(delta);`. (Only a comment, not an answer, because nobody can know what the ... is wrong with your code...)

Comment: Unless you can figure out why this is happening, it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: You are only updating one bullet which is at "index". Make a for loop to loop through all entries in ArrayList and call update() for each one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what your `index` parameter is supposed to be (the stuff you do with it doesn't make any sense to me), but it sure seems to be the source of the problem.

First of all, in the `shoot` method, you only increment it if it's non-zero, so if it is zero, it will forever be zero.

Then in `render` you are only updating a single bullet instead of all the bullets in the array.

The clearest solution to me (although again I don't know what you were trying to track with the `index` parameter) would be to completely remove the `index` parameter. Then replace ArrayList with libgdx's Array class, which allows fast modification and removal during a loop, and change your render method like this.

```
public void update(float delta) {
    for (int i=bullets.size-1; i>=0; i--) { //count backward for safe removals
        PlayerBullet bullet = bullets.get(i);
        for(GameObject t : list){
            if(t instanceof Brick){
                if(bullet.hits(t.getHitBox()) == 1){
                    bullets.removeIndex(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```